# How to join every newline Strings within single or double quote

Tags: linux, awk, sed

How to join every newline Strings within single or double quote separated by comma.

### Example:

I have below names..

```
$ cat file

James kurt
Suji sane
Bhujji La
Loki Hapa
```

### Desired:

```
"James kurt", "Suji sane", "Bhujji La", "Loki Hapa"
```

### EDIT:

My Side Efforts:

Below which i have done but there i'm completing it in two steps, jst curious if it can be clubbed into one only.

```
 $ awk '{print "\x22" $1" "$2 "\x22"}'| tr '\n' ','
```

Comment: On SO we do encourage users to add their efforts, so please do add your efforts in your question.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to do that but just updated which i worked around.

Comment: Be advised that the notation `\x22` is a Gnu awk extension and not used by any other awk version. It is always better to use octal numbers. For the double-quote, you can use `\042`

Comment: Big thank you guys,  with `awk '{print "\x22" $0 "\x22"}'`  here `$0` makes space before and after Name's hence i'm still using stricktly `$1$2` , example.. `" James kurt "` if I'll use `$0`  .. My  two cents to you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First print all lines with the `"` and then join the lines with a comma:

```
< file xargs -d '\n' printf '"%s"\n' | paste -sd,
```

Instead of newline you could just remove trailing (or leading comma):

```
< file xargs -d '\n' printf '"%s",' | sed 's/,$//'
< file xargs -d '\n' printf ',"%s"' | cut -c2-
< file xargs -d '\n' printf ', "%s"' | cut -c3-   # with space after comma
```

With sed add the `"` and hold the lines, then on last line replace newline with comma and remove the leading command and print:

```
sed -n 's/^/"/;s/$/"/;H;${x;s/\n/, /g;s/^, //;p}' file
```

You were close! The `" "` in your attempt adds a space between the line and `"`. You could:

```
awk '{print "\x22" $0 "\x22"}' | tr '\n' ',' |
# and then remove trailing comma:
sed 's/,$//'
```

But joining the lines with `paste` is just simpler then replacing newlines with comma and removing the last one:

```
awk '{print "\x22" $0 "\x22"}' | paste -sd,
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -v lines=$(wc -l < Input_file) -v s1="\"" '
BEGIN{
  OFS=", "
}
{
  printf("%s%s",s1 $0 s1,lines==FNR?ORS:OFS)
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v lines=$(wc -l < Input_file) -v s1="\"" '   ##Starting awk program, creating variable lines which has total number of lines in Input_file and creating s1 variable with " in it.
BEGIN{                                            ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  OFS=", "                                        ##Setting OFS value as comma space here.
}
{
  printf("%s%s",s1 $0 s1,lines==FNR?ORS:OFS)      ##Printing current line and either printing space or new line as per condition.
}
'  Input_file                                     ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{printf "%s",(NR==1?"":",")"\042"$0"\042"}END{print ""}'
```

Note that the last `END` statement is only used to add the last new-line to the output. This makes it POSIX complaint.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/.*/"&"/mg;s/\n/, /g' file
```

Slurp file into the pattern space, surround lines by double quotes and replace newlines by a comma and a space.

Alternative:

```
sed -z 's/\n$//;s/.*/"&"/mg;s/\n/, /g;s/$/\n/' file
```